# How does Docker Desktop work on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I was using Docker CLI when working with Linux. But recently I reinstalled my system so wanted to try Desktop version: enabled KVM, made sure file sharing thing is working, initialized pass thing, managed to install it and run. Looks like it's working,but how do I use it now? For example, in CLI I could've just wrote `docker-compose -f file up -d` and it was running. Now I write almost the same thing, yeah, it is running, but none of it appears in Docker desktop app. So what's the purpose of it? How do I run things so they appear there? I'm kind of confused what's the benefits of it and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [install page](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/):

> ℹImportant
>
> Docker Desktop on Linux runs a Virtual Machine (VM) so creates and uses a custom docker context `desktop-linux` on startup.
>
> This means images and containers deployed on the Linux Docker Engine (before installation) are not available in Docker Desktop for Linux.
>
> For more information see [What is the difference between Docker Desktop for Linux and Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#what-is-the-difference-between-docker-desktop-for-linux-and-docker-engine).

So while Docker Desktop’s VM is running, you should be able to use `docker context use desktop-linux` to switch to its context and interact with it on the command line. Keep in mind that the default context will also be running.

You can use various other commands to manage [Docker Contexts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/), like `docker context ls` to list them.

Deciding whether the management GUI offered by Docker Desktop is worth it is up to you. Other UIs (mostly read-only) exist.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide please an example of a another ui that works with default context? Also, do I need to do anything specific to uninstall desktop now?

Comment: Specific [uninstall instructions](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/) are available. Portainer CE is an example of a Docker web UI. Podman Desktop also does Docker IIRC. I do not use any of these.

Comment: yeah, found it, already uninstalled and tried Portainer, looks good, think will stick with that, also why you don't use them?

Comment: No particular reason, I just don’t feel I need them with my ~10 containers.